# inline afterwards element to a block element

Tags: html, css

Here is the simple html

```html
<p> some text here </p>
<a href="#">more</a>
```

and the css I tried

```css
p+a{
  color: #f00; 
  display: inline-block;
  /* also tried float: left; */
}
```

To bring up the output as this

> some text here **more**

I want **more** in the line of p.

Comment: explain what you want?

Comment: You may put the anchor inside your paragraph and add a class to it. Then you'll be able to style the class. Would that work for you?

Comment: @Shahbaz I want "more" in the line of p.

Comment: @kleinfreund I couldn't place inside p coz I'm using a template

Comment: Then just format the paragraph as `inline-block` as well. ;)

Comment: You are missing replace this line <a href="#">more</a>

Comment: @kleinfreund Oh! it was mistake here only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is a block level element. So you couldn't inline to `a`. Therefore you need to style your `p` as `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` and then give `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` to `a`

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3Ufs/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the paragraph `display: inline-block;` as well, because it is a block-level element. Therefor it automatically takes the available space and pushes the anchor to a new line. Also you'll need to add the closing `"` to your `href`-attribute.

(If you're able to manipulate the markup of the paragraph – just add the anchor inside of it.)

**HMTL:**

```
<p>some text here</p>
<a href="#">more</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
}

p + a {
    color: #f00; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note: Please use classes to style things like that instead of elements. Add a class to your anchor and select it with `p + .read-more` or something like that.

Comment: There is something wrong on my template when I tried inline-block it was displaying none but when I tried inline it is okay for the website.

Comment: I tried it on a blank html-page and it worked just fine. I believe, displaying a natural block-level element as inline is not really an appropriate way to do it.

Comment: What did happen? Maybe I can help you with that, if you explain this exactly.

Comment: when I apply padding value to p it displays none.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

**CSS:**

```
p > a {
    color: #f00; 
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>some text here <a href="#">more</a></p>
```

Comment: Note: The author is not able to change the markup. He can't put the anchor inside the paragraph at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

just add the below css to your stylesheet.

```
p{ dislpay:inline-block;}
```

`P` is a block level element make it `inline-block` so next inline element come up next to `p` tag.

Comment: Why are you copying answers, others already provided a couple of minutes before you?